# \[NSString stringWithUTF8String: "hello"\] returns nil. Huh?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying to solve a problem in an iOS program that was recently ported to 64 bits.

I discovered that stringWithUTF8String always returns nil, and I was able to narrow the problem to a very simple 12 liners. Here is my main.m file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string a("hello");
  NSString * s1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: a.c_str()];
  NSString * s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: a.c_str()];
  NSString * s3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "hello"];

  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
  }
}
```

s1, s2, and s3 are nil when I debug the program on an iPad Air 2 !

I am inclined to think there might be either an obvious problem in the code, or there is a configuration error in the project settings since it was ported to 64 bits (this code used to work perfectly).

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance

EDIT :
I just tested the code in a new project under OSX (File|New Project|Command Line Tool), and it works.
So, it seems that my problem is due to the project settings. I do not know where to look although.

Comment: Your sample code runs as expected for me. (That is, `s3` isn't `nil`.)

Comment: @Aaron : Was this on an iPad ?

Comment: No, the iPad Air simulator. If you're searching your project settings, maybe take a look at your optimizations? (It might be optimized out.)

Comment: How do you know you're getting nil?

Comment: @Hot Licks : by setting a breakpoint and by examining the variables

Comment: Use NSLog or do `po myString` in the console.  The debugger variable display is highly unreliable.

Comment: @HotLicks : ouch! You were right. NSLog works, and po informs me that the variable may have been optimized out.